# how i write this custom distribution power function distribution i want to write in family distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

this is basic pareto distriibution

```
data = {1.312, 1.314, 1.479, 1.552, 1.700, 1.803, 1.861, 
        1.865, 1.944, 1.958, 1.966, 1.997, 2.006, 2.021,
        2.027, 2.055, 2.063, 2.098, 2.14, 2.179, 2.224,
        2.240, 2.253, 2.270, 2.272, 2.274, 2.301, 2.301,
        2.359, 2.382, 2.382, 2.426, 2.434, 2.435, 2.478,
        2.490, 2.511, 2.514, 2.535, 2.554, 2.566, 2.57,
        2.586, 2.629, 2.633, 2.642, 2.648, 2.684, 2.697,
        2.726, 2.770, 2.773, 2.800, 2.809, 2.818, 2.821,
        2.848, 2.88, 2.954, 3.012, 3.067, 3.084, 3.090,
        3.096, 3.128, 3.233, 3.433, 3.585, 3.585};

dist[λ_] = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 1 - x^(-λ)}, {x, 1, ∞}];

Λ = λ /. FindDistributionParameters[data, dist[λ]]
(*    1.14273    *)

ProbabilityPlot[data, dist[Λ]]
```

i want to write power function also cdf is like that
[image]
if anyone can help please

Comment: Have you seen [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)?

Comment: Actually, did you already look at all the possible forms of `ParetoDistribution[]`?

Comment: i want to write like this function   dD = ProbabilityDistribution[ Piecewise[{{x^2/9, 0 < x <= 3}}], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];